# How does marking a field as transient make it possible to serialise an object

Tags: java, serialization, transient

```
public class Foo implements java.io.Serializable {
   private int v1;
   private static double v2;
   private Loan v3 = new Loan();
}
```

Options:
A. An instance of Foo can be serialized because Foo implements Serializable.
B. An instance of Foo cannot be serialized because Foo contains a non-serializable instance variable v3.
C. If you mark v3 as transient, an instance of Foo is serializable.
D. b and c

Answer: D

Explanation: An object may not be serialized even though its class implements `java.io.Serializable`, because it may contain non-serializable instance variables.

**Now my question is:**

As far as I know, transient is [used](http://www.devx.com/tips/Tip/13726) to turn off serialization. Then how is transient in this case, helping us to serialize foo?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`transient` doesn't disable serialization altogether; it just marks members that won't be serialized.  It's typically used for stuff that would be incorrect or irrelevant when the object is unserialized, or stuff that it'd be less-than-safe to store (passwords, decrypted data, that sort of thing), or non-serializable stuff that could be easily reconstructed.

In this case, i assume the `Loan` class isn't serializable.  (If it were, then A would be correct.)  Marking `v3` as transient just tells Java not to worry about that field, but go ahead and serialize the others.  This means an unserialized `Foo` might have a null `v3`.  If you want to store the `Loan` as well, you'd need to either keep track of enough info to recreate it at will, or change class `Loan` so that it implements `java.io.Serializable` as well.

Alternatively, there are methods you could implement (`writeObject`, `readObject`) if you need control over serialization.  But that can be a bit of a hassle.

Answer (score 2):

> Then how is transient in this case,
>   helping us to serialize foo?

Because it allows you to serialize the *rest* of Foo, the other members that *are* serializable.

Answer (score 0):

First, are you sure that Loan is not serializable? If it is, then B doesn't apply.

On the other hand, if it indeed is not, then B and C are right. `transient` doesn't turn off serialization generally, but only for the field with which it's associated. Thus, serializing Foo would not transmit a value for the v3 field. On the receiving end, when re-initializing the Foo instance, the serialization mechanism wouldn't try to read that field from the stream, and would leave it null.