# Change the value of transient in datatable with cell edit

Tags: java, primefaces

Hi guys I have a datatable with a transient in the entity as a total of an addition, i have to be able to modify the value of the transient for each row, i am doing it with cell editor, but when i try to change it, it goes back to its original value,

```
    private Double v1;

    private Double v2;

    @transient
    private Double total;

    get{return getV1()+getV2()}
```

Can a transient be updated in memory and alter the list in the datatable?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use of serializable and transient in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5177013/use-of-serializable-and-transient-in-java)

Comment: It Was not the same, but i already solved it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it making the calculation in the ManageBean instead of the entity, so now when I change the value in memory it can be done with out any problem