# Java - Serialization - NotSerializableException Issue

Tags: java, serialization, io

I'm currently working on a student database using Java only and have two particular lists I would like to save. Students and Profiles(To login with). I'm currently testing out serialization on Students only to get it to work but have been getting a weird issue.

---

**My Student object classes and code are as follows:**

> Student.java
>
> StudentsCollection.java

Students creates my Student object(Self explanatory) and my StudentsCollection() instantiates a list of type Student which stores my Student objects, when trying to save/load the objects I use this code and get the following exception thrown:

```
    /**
     * Save student collection
     */
   public void saveCollection(){
      try {
         FileOutputStream e = new FileOutputStream("students.ser");
         ObjectOutputStream outputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(e);
         for(Students i : this.list){
             outputStream.writeObject(i);
         }
         outputStream.flush();
         outputStream.close();
      } catch (IOException var3) {
          var3.printStackTrace();
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog((Component)null, "Error. Cannot save database.");
      }

   }

    /**
     * Open student collection
     */
   public void openCollection(){
      try {
         FileInputStream e = new FileInputStream("students.ser");
         ObjectInputStream inputSteam = new ObjectInputStream(e);
          while(inputSteam.readObject() != null){
              this.list.add((Students)inputSteam.readObject());
          }
      } catch (FileNotFoundException var3) {
          var3.printStackTrace();
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "File not found");
      } catch (IOException var4) {
          var4.printStackTrace();
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "IO Exception");
      } catch (ClassNotFoundException var5) {
          var5.printStackTrace();
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Required class not found");
      }

   }
```

And the following exception is printed:

```
java.io.NotSerializableException: java.util.Scanner
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1183)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1547)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1508)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1431)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1177)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:347)
at jdatabase.objects.students.StudentsCollection.saveCollection(StudentsCollection.java:539)
at jdatabase.main.MainController$1.run(MainController.java:22)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:312)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:733)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

I would also like to point out that students.ser is actually created in my project explorer but exceptions are still being thrown, even when trying to use openCollection() errors are thrown, however I'd like to tackle saveCollection() properly first

Comment: I can't see it in your code snippets but the error reads as though it's trying to serialize a Scanner. By any chance does your Student class have a Scanner as a field?

Comment: Sigh you're right, once I lost my project I had asked a friend to decompile my JAR and some code jumbled up, the default constructor was requesting input for student name for some reason.. Will try removing all the Scanners and see if it works

Comment: Does any of your class have `Scanner` field?

Comment: Yes, I've found the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You did not post your `Student.java`, so I am guessing here. Is there a field of type `java.util.Scanner` in the `Student` class? If there is, delete it, or mark it as `transient`:

```
private transient Scanner someField;
```

The `transient` modifier will prevent the field from being serialized.

Comment: You can add some info that `transient` prevents serialization of field with this modifier.

Comment: Yes when my project was decompiled(lost source a while ago) it caused some weird code, all my constructors had some a Scanner requesting input for some reason

Answer (score 1):

There is an <strike>Object</strike> `Students` in your `this.list` that references the `Scanner`. Remove the reference and you will be fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can serialize an object only if all of its class members are also implementing Serializable.
As RobAu mentioned, Scanner is not serializeable.

You can find a good tutorial here: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaSerialization/article.html

All fields marked with transient will not be serialized. See here for more details:
[How does marking a field as transient make it possible to serialise an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5177013/use-of-serializable-and-transient-in-java)

Comment: Yea I was aware of that, wasn't aware the Scanner objects were even in there that's why when reading that stack trace I was a bit confused!

Answer (score 0):

Since scanner class does not implement Serializable interface, there must be some field in your class asking for input through scanner, hence the error.