# Java - Serialization - Grabbing number of objects

Tags: java, serialization

### Java - Serialization - Grabbing number of objects in file

---

I'm trying to retrieve my objects from my serialized file and re-add them to my file. There seems to be an issue, no exception is being thrown but nothing is being printed in my console when running my method. Before continuing here is my code:

```
public boolean openCollection(){
        try {
            FileInputStream e = new FileInputStream("profiles.ser");
            ObjectInputStream inputStream = new ObjectInputStream(e);
            List<Profile> profiles = (List<Profile>) inputStream.readObject();

            //De-obscure
            for(Profile p : profiles){
                String unObcName = deobscure(p.getName()); //Original name
                String unObcSurname = deobscure(p.getSurname()); //Original surname
                String unObcUsername = deobscure(p.getUsername()); //Original username
                String unObcPassword = deobscure(p.getPassword()); //Original password

                p.setName(unObcName);
                p.setSurname(unObcSurname);
                p.setUsername(unObcUsername);
                p.setPassword(unObcPassword);

                //Debugging
                System.out.println("DE-OBSCURE - Profile name: " + p.getName() +"\n"+
                        "Profile surname: " + p.getSurname() +"\n"+
                        "Profile username: " + p.getUsername() +"\n"+
                        "Profile password: " + p.getPassword());
                this.profiles.add(p);
            }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException var3) {
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No profiles found, please create a profile!");
                    final CreateProfile createProfile = new CreateProfile();
                    createProfile.setVisible(true);
                }
            });
            return false;
        } catch (IOException var4) {
            var4.printStackTrace();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "IO Exception");
            return false;
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException var5) {
            var5.printStackTrace();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Required class not found");
            return false;
        }
    return true;
}
```

---

> This is the serialization method

```
 public void saveCollection(){

    //Obscure the data
    List<Profile> saveProfiles = new ArrayList<>();
    for(Profile p : profiles){
        String obcName = obscure(p.getName());
        String obcSurname = obscure(p.getSurname());
        String obcUsername = obscure(p.getUsername());
        String obcPassword = obscure(p.getPassword());

        p.setName(obcName);
        p.setSurname(obcSurname);
        p.setUsername(obcUsername);
        p.setPassword(obcPassword);

        //Debugging
        System.out.println("DEBUG - Profile name: " + p.getName() + "\n" +
                "Profile surname: " + p.getSurname() + "\n" +
                "Profile username: " + p.getUsername() + "\n" +
                "Profile password: " + p.getPassword());

        saveProfiles.add(p);
    }

    //Save it
    try {
        FileOutputStream e = new FileOutputStream("profiles.ser");
        ObjectOutputStream outputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(e);
        outputStream.writeObject(saveProfiles);
        outputStream.flush();
        outputStream.close();
    } catch (IOException var3) {
        var3.printStackTrace();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error. Cannot save database.");
    }

}
```

When creating a profile the details are being obscured properly, here are the results:

> DEBUG - Profile name: OBF:1u2a1toa1w8v1tok1u30
>
> Profile surname: OBF:1u2a1toa1w8v1tok1u30
>
> Profile username: OBF:1u2a1toa1w8v1tok1u30
>
> Profile password: OBF:1u2a1toa1w8v1tok1u30

However when running openCollection() nothing is being printed into the console.

**NOTE:** The profile details were all 'admin' which is why all the data looks the same

Comment: How did you Serialize?

Comment: There is no method for retrieving the number of objects. That would be contrary to the nature of a *stream*. If you want that number, you have to write it to your stream manually.

Comment: Eliot I will be adding the saveCollection() to the original post. @Holger I thought so, issue I previously had was that the openCollection() would keep throwing me an EOFException cause like you said, there isn't a direct method that actually knows how 'many' objects there are in your file, so readObject() would ran out of objects and throw the exception which I found very annoying and couldn't leave it throwing that exception in the console all the time

Comment: You're making your life difficult. Instead of writing the size of the list, then writing each element of the list, why don't you simply write the list itself. Reading would be as simple as `List<Profile> profiles = (List<Profile>) objectInputStream.readObject();` That said, if you write the size with `writeObject()`, you should read it with `readObject()`. `read()` reads only one byte.

Comment: Alright thanks JB, I'll try that out and see how it goes

Comment: If you write the number using `outputStream.writeObject(profiles.size())` you are writing an object and have to read it with a corresponding `int size=(Integer)inputStream.readObject();`. Otherwise you have to use `writeInt` and `readInt` for storing it as a primitive `int` value. But simply writing the `List` is the better choice. You can also write an array of objects to get rid of the unchecked cast warning in the read code.

Comment: I went ahead and changed a couple things which did indeed cut down the code. I wrote added the desired noise to the data, added it to the list and wrote the whole list object. I then read that list and save it, iterate through each element and de-obscure it. I posted the results in the end

Comment: Seems like a rehash of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24825958/java-serialization-eofexception-issue

Comment: Like I said, I don't have any EOFExceptions being printed out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a while checking things out I figured out that the issue was simply with my deobscuring method. I have now edited it and replace it with the following:

```
/**
 * @param str Obscured String
 * @return Unobscured String
 */
private String deobscure(String s){
    if (s.startsWith(__OBFUSCATE)) s = s.substring(4);

    byte[] b = new byte[s.length() / 2];
    int l = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i += 4)
    {
        if (s.charAt(i)=='U')
        {
            i++;
            String x = s.substring(i, i + 4);
            int i0 = Integer.parseInt(x, 36);
            byte bx = (byte)(i0>>8);
            b[l++] = bx;

        }
        else
        {
            String x = s.substring(i, i + 4);
            int i0 = Integer.parseInt(x, 36);
            int i1 = (i0 / 256);
            int i2 = (i0 % 256);
            byte bx = (byte) ((i1 + i2 - 254) / 2);
            b[l++] = bx;
        }
    }

    return new String(b, 0, l,StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
}
```

> Original Profile name: "Admin"
>
> Obscured Profile name: "OBF:1npu1toa1w8v1tok1nsc
>
> After de-obscuring Profile name: "Admin"

Thus the method now works as intended.