# recursive serialization in java

Tags: java, serialization

I am working with serialization in Java for the first time.

I have read that Java recursively serializes objects.

Say I have a class `Diet` that holds objects of type `fruit` which holds objects like `apple`, `banana`, `pineapple`.

As I have understood it, once I serialize an object of type `Diet` java stores the other objects in the same vein.

But: do all classes I intend to be (co-)serialized have to implement `Serializable` or only the "top-class" (here: `Diet`)?

Comment: Yes, unless they're transient.

Comment: Note that it's the *fields* that would need to be transient. (The classes can't be transient.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All classes needs to implement `Serializable`, not just the class of the root object.

Note that you can mark certain fields as `transient` if you don't want serialization to traverse those fields. See [How does marking a field as transient make it possible to serialise an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5177013/how-does-marking-a-field-as-transient-make-it-possible-to-serialise-an-object).